# Swift make border rof uiimageview outside

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I want to make a border to imageview and here is my code

```
    let view = UIImageView()
    view.layer.borderWidth = 4
    view.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha:0.4).cgColor
    view.layer.cornerRadius = 40
    view.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

But this only adds border inside of imageview,how can i make it outside?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Create a UIView and make it slightly larger than the image, then add the image to the center. Setting the background color will make the border a different color.

```
let border = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 251, height: 251))
border.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

let image = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 250, height: 250))
image.center = border.center
image.image = ...
border.addSubview(image)
```

Comment: thanks! I had to change few thinks but the idea is right:)

Comment: You don't need to make 2 separate views to make the border of an image view.

Answer (score 2):

This can help you. Add a border layer using CALayer you can customize border color and border frame, also the other parameters.

```
let borderLayer = CALayer()
let borderFrame = CGRect(x: -1.0, y: -1.0, width: imageView.frame.size.height + 2.0, height: imageView.frame.size.height + 2.0)
borderLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
borderLayer.frame = borderFrame
borderLayer.cornerRadius = 5.0
borderLayer.borderWidth = 2.0
borderLayer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
imageView.layer.addSublayer(borderLayer)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways to do it.

**1. Using storyboard**

If you are doing it in the storyboard, you can give the layer related properties directly in **User Defined Runtime Attributes** column in the storyboard itself.

**Screenshot:**
[image]

**2. Using Code**

```
let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 240, height: 128))
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "Image")
        imageView.layer.borderWidth = 4
        imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 40
        imageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        self.view.addSubview(imageView)
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Edit:**
**Screenshot after changing alpha of borderColor**

[image]

Comment: It still shows inside.Change alpha to 0.5 to see that

Comment: alpha of image or borderColor?

Comment: I have update the answer after changing the alpha of borderColor. Have a look.

Comment: Now you see that border is still inside of image

Comment: Yes. This is because the border is added on the image. It is a part of the image. It is not added outside the bounds of the image. So when you decrease the alpha of border color you see the image behind it.

Comment: My question was how to make border outisde of image